# Table not sitting at 100% height within DIV tags

Tags: html, css

I have setup a table within a DIV tag at the following link:

http://jsfiddle.net/yVDXQ/122/

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

.container {
background: yellow;
min-height: 100%;
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

i was wondering if i can get my table to inherit the 100% height from the DIV it sits within?

Would be greatful for some assistance.

Comment: http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/howtoset100tableheightinhtml.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `height:100%` to `.container` and it will stretch it.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/yVDXQ/124/)

Comment: I tried that but couldn't get it to work. Must have done something wrong, though, because yours works great.

Comment: The reason yours is different is because your .container is min-height, you need to change it to height:100%

Comment: You were nearly there, you had `height:100%` on the `html` and `body` tags, but you just needed it on the `.container` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply a height: 100% to the container div, check out your updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/msbodetti/yVDXQ/125/

Div CSS:

```
.container {
    background: yellow;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```